# Why does my output not capitalize python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is wrong? i want the output name to be capitalized.

```
name = input('Full name:') 
fullname =name.split(" ")

Name = fullname[0].rjust(23)
Surname = fullname[1].rjust(20)

print(f'Name: {Name.capitalize()} \nSurname: {Surname.capitalize()}')
```

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: it does not matter if the input is capitalized or not the output is always in lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.capitalize` only capitalizes the first character of your string. But you've right-justified it, so this character is a space.

Try justifying in the print:

```
Name = fullname[0] 
Surname = fullname[1]
print(f'Name: {Name.capitalize():>23s} \nSurname {Surname.capitalize():>20s}')
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure what attracted the downvotes – it seems like a perfectly reasonably question.